# Detect and handle when a database query goes wrong

Tags: sql, qt, postgresql

My problem is I want all my queries must return results after a limited time. AFAIK, `postgres` has 2 options for this: `connect_timeout` when open a connection to database, and `statement_timeout` for a query.

This lead to 2 problems:

1. I must estimate how much time the query is run. My approach is setup
   a worst case scenario: with a preset bandwidth to db server, a query
   with a lot record... to determine it, but I think this ain't a smart
   way. Are there any better ideas/patterns... to handle this?
2. The network problem. Assume the network is bad with heavy packets
       loss, high ping as hell... the query from clients, and the result from
       the server are stuck ... Of course we can set a
       timeout from the code, but I think it will be complicated due to
       handle resource and other things, and it's duplicated with the
       database timeout mechanism. Are there anyway to handle this?

Another version of the story: when a query take a long time, I want to distinguish: this query is all good, just has too many records, wait for it, and no, the query is "broken",don't wait for it...

Ps : I found this link, but this is for SQL Server 2005 :(

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1338/finding-a-sql-server-process-percentage-complete-with-dmvs/

Comment: For what purpose do you need the well defined timeout? Why do think it is important for your application?

Comment: I need the info to report to the upper layer. My team-leader want a report, not something run around  for a long time.

Comment: But why does your team-leader think so? Does he want to prevent your application from blocking a long time due to synchronous DB access? Or does he think the queries are not important enough to wait for them?

Comment: Yes, prevent the block and few more things. The queries result varies from just a number to hundreds of thousands records, when it takes time, the user should distinguish: this query is all good, just has too many records, wait for it, _and_ no, the query is "broken",don't wait for it, contact tech-support ASAP...

Comment: Do you really need hundred of thousands of records? If you do then you shouldn't mind waiting a bit. If you don't then why not limit the result or use a cursor?

Comment: Yes, if the user queries data saved a month ago, it will reach about 500,000 records. Users also require to access data with no restriction. And what do you mean a cursor?

Comment: BTW, the network can be unstable and we must handle that.

Comment: You do not explain what the actual operational problem you're trying to solve here is. This sounds more like a candidate for log analysis / pg_stat_statements than for a query timeout.

Comment: Another version of the story: when a query take a long time, I want to distinguish: this query is all good, just has too many records, wait for it, and no, the query is "broken",don't wait for it...

Comment: You will not be able to do what you want. It's a recognised extremely hard problem in computing theory. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Answer (score 3):

As you already mentioned, it is hard to predict how long a query runs (due to the query itself and its parameters, due to network, due to server load).

Anyway you should move the SQL queries into QThreads. This allows your application from serving the GUI while the queries run.

Also I would not try to solve this by timeouts. You will get into a lot of trouble because you will fail to choose the right timeouts for each query and each situation. Instead provide a way of cancelling queries by a button or a dialog so the user can decide if it is sensible to continue waiting or not.

Comment: Thank, I do implement QThread to do the interactions with the database. If there isn't any solution, I will follow your advice, let's the user decide the action. So I think I'll need a query indicators or something similars to give info to the user

Comment: Remember accept my answer if you don't get a better one.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do:

> when a query take a long time, I want to distinguish: this query is all good, just has too many records, wait for it, and no, the query is "broken",don't wait for it.

is just not going to work out. You appear to require a solution to the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), a fundamentally hard problem in computer science.

You must decide how long is acceptable for a query to run, and set a timeout. There is no reliable way to predict how long it should run, except by looking at how long other similar queries took to run before. Nor is there any way to tell the difference between a correct (but slow) query and one that is going to run forever. That's particularly true when things like `WITH RECURSIVE` or PL/PgSQL functions are involved.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the queries in a specific class the object of which resides in a separate thread and wait for a timeout for the object to quit :

```
databaseObject->performQuery();

QThread * th = databaseObject->thread();
th->quit();
th->wait(2000);

if(th->isRunning())
{
    th->terminate();
    return false;
}
else
    return true;
```

Comment: Thank, but how do you estimate the time out? The query will be varies from a few to hundreds of thousands records.

Comment: @Tiana987642 I doubt there is any simple way to estimate the query time. You can have your own maximum acceptable time for query. The timeout is dependent to your needs.