# Modify and rebuild QSqlDatabase lib to check connection state

Tags: c++, qt, postgresql

in an attempt to **[solve my own problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831313/detect-and-handle-when-a-database-query-goes-wrong)** I want to implement a function to check the connection state to a Postgres database (use `PQconnectPoll`)

I got the [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/libpq.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT), and the [source code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/57756e72adf2081137b97f0e689dd16c770d10b1:src/sql/drivers/psql/qsql_psql.cpp#L124). I think I will just add the function, rebuild and replace the library. Pseudo:

```
    enum state_t {STARTED,MADE,BAD...};
    
    state_t checkDBConn(){
    
    switch(PQstatus(connection))
    {
        
        state_t feedback ;
        case CONNECTION_STARTED:
            feedback =STARTED ;
            break;
    
        case CONNECTION_MADE:
            feedback = MADE;
            break;
    .
    .
    .
        default:
            feedback = BAD;
    }
    }
```

I haven't done this before, so I will need your ideas about my approach:

1. Are there better ways?
2. A check list before do this? The more detail, the better :)

Any comments will be appreciated :)

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish by doing this that you can't already do with QtSQL directly? As things stand, if Qt figures out there's a connection problem then the function call that's running the query will return with an error. And if it doesn't know there's something wrong, this function will do no good. Perhaps you're assuming that `PQstatus` will *test* the connection in some way? It does not. It just tells you what the current *known* status, according to the client, of the connection is.

Comment: Yes, I think it will test the connection. You read my original problem, after a few argue, the scope is limited to only network problem. My team-leader confirm C# implementation of `postgres` can do such a thing: call the query with a timeout parameter, disconnect to the database server, and when timeout, it return error code. I'm looking for something similar with Qt.

Comment: Your team leader is wrong or you misunderstood what they told you. nPgSQL (presumably what you're talking about with "the C# implementation of postgres") can *not* run a query then disconnect and leave the query running, because PostgreSQL its self does not support leaving queries running with the client disconnected.

Comment: nPgSQL *can* run a query with a timeout set, but that's also possible with QtSQL: just `SET statement_timeout` before you run your query. You already rejected that in your previous question, so it isn't clear to me what you actually want.

Comment: I do say with him about `statement_timeout`, but kinda like he want to handle the situation when the client does the query and then lost the connection the the db server. AFAIK, `statement_timeout` is on the server side?

Comment: "handle" how? What do you expect to happen if the client runs a query then loses the connection? The query will either complete (if the server doesn't notice the disconnect until it finishes) or error and automatically roll back. You can't "handle" anything.

Comment: He want the upper-layer's responsive, so a query under bad network connection ain't take much time and must report back the error code.  His number is 3 secs, except a "killer" query can take up to 500,000 records, which I must estimate it own time-out.

Comment: I will refrain from expressing my full opinion of your team leader's ideas, understanding of TCP/IP, understanding of the client/server database architecture, etc. I think you have been asked to find a solution to an impossible problem based on fundamental misunderstandings of how the technology works and what is practical to achieve - though it's also possible you are misunderstanding what you're being asked for, or I'm misunderstanding what you describe. In any case I don't think I can help you. Good luck, and I hope you find some way to make sense of it at some point.

Comment: I will talk to my TL again, to clarify the problem. Thank for your time :) I hope if I make it clear, you can help me :)